# XPath: How to sort a map?

Tags: xpath, xpath-3.1

I'm using a `map` for counting the number occurrences of, for example, each possible value of the `attr` attribute of the `elem` nodes:

```xml
<root>
    <elem attr="a"/>
    <elem attr="b"/>
    <elem attr="b"/>
    <elem         />
    <elem attr="a"/>
    <elem attr="c"/>
    <elem attr="b"/>
</root>
```

```bash
fold-left(
    //elem/@attr,
    map{},
    function($m,$a) {map:put($m, $a, sum((1, $m($a))))}
)
```

Resulting map:

```json
{
  "a": 2,
  "b": 3,
  "c": 1
}
```

Now, using this `map`, I would like to sort the integer values in descending order and emit their associated key. The expected "output" would be:

```
b
a
c
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the map in a variable then it's possible to call `fn:sort` on the keys while using the associated values as "sort keys":

```bash
let
    $map := map{ "a": 2, "b": 3, "c": 1 }
return
    $map => map:keys() => sort((), function($key) { -$map($key) })
```

```
b
a
c
```

---

###### ASIDE

You can also define a `map:sort` function for maps, which would return a sequence of keys:

```bash
function(
    $map       as map(*),
    $collation as xs:string?,
    $valuate   as function(xs:anyAtomicType, item()*) as xs:anyAtomicType*
) as xs:anyAtomicType*
{
    sort(
        map:keys($map),
        $collation,
        function($key) { $valuate($key, $map($key)) }
    )
}
```

```bash
let $map:sort := function (...) {...}
return
    map{ "a": 2, "b": 3, "c": 1 }
    => $map:sort((), function($k,$v) { -$v })
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why you would want a map for this. It's essentially a grouping-and-sorting problem, therefore much easier in XSLT or XQuery, but if it has to be pure XPath, you can use

```
let $in := . 
return (distinct-values(//@attr) 
        => sort((), function($a){-count($in//@attr[.=$a])}))
```